# Ruby on Rails Write a redirect for a dynamic URL to a static URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, url, redirect, syntax

Is there a simple way to write a ruby if statement to redirect a dynamic page to a static page?

I’m writing this in my pages controller where the site pages are generated. This is what I’m attempting to do.

If “/index/page1”
redirect_to “page2”
return
end

This redirects all the pages created in the pages controller to “page2”. I know the syntax is incorrect. I need help in writing out the correct way to test for the first condition.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

Here is an update / more information to my question.

Here is my show action in the PagesController

```
def show
    @page = Page.find_by_url_path("/#{params[:url_path]}")

    layout = "templates/#{@page.pageable.class.name.underscore}"
 
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render layout: layout }
end
```

I need to write an if statement that looks for one specific URL that gets generated. This page is created by the show action.

```
e.g. https://host.com/products/page1
```

Then redirect it to another specific URL. This is a static page on the site.

```
e.g. https://host.com/page2
```

I am having difficulty in writing the if statement to find the first page. This is what I've tried.

```
if "/products/page1"
   redirt_to "/page2"
   return
end
```

Depending where I put the code within the show action, I either get a double render error (as subparry explains below). Or I redirect all the pages generated through the show action to "/page2".

This application was written by a more experienced Ruby developer and I'm doing my best to maintain / update it. If I need to post more detailed information, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi!
I'm not sure what your intent is. Are you trying to redirect every page from PagesController to another url? or is it just a single page from PagesController that needs redirection?

Comment: Hi subparry, thank you for responding. Just wanting to redirect a single page from PagesController. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as usual with these kind of requirements, there are many ways to achieve it.
As you know, different pages (views) in controllers are represented by instance methods (or Actions), for example I can imagine your PagesController looking something like this:

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def page1
    # do something...
  end

  def page2
    #do something else...
  end
end
```

So, the easiest way would be to trigger a redirect from page1 `redirect_to "https://host.com/page2"`, I don't know the reasons behind the decision to redirect. If it is a temporary redirect, it might be the best solution because of ease of change later, but if it is a more permanent redirection, I would implement it at the web server level (Nginx for example)

It depends on your use case.

PS: Don't forget that if you redirect in your action, it does not imply a return, so if you have more code below and another call to render or redirect, it will fail (double render error) so either you remove further renders/redirects or insert an early return.

EDIT:
Ok, now I understand better your case. You have a model called Pages which has a column called `url_path` which details the location of each page.

So, if I understand correctly, you'll have to do the conditional statement like this:

```rb
  def show
    if params[:url_path] == 'page1'
      redirect_to 'https://host.com/page2'
      return
    end
    # Rest of action code...
  end
```

I don't know for sure how are paths stored in `url_path`, but you get the idea!

PS2: When you write `if 'products/page1'` you are basically saying `if true` and always entering the condition because only nil and false are falsy values, everything else is truthy.

Comment: subparry - Thank you for your answer, it is helpful! The reason for the redirect is for a temporary promotion. And as you guessed correctly, I'm attempting to build it this way to make it easier to revert back later. As my main issue is writing the code to find the first URL. Is it best I attempt this by writing the if statement in a new controller action? What would that look like? Or can I write it within the show action? With the correct syntax of course. I updated my question with more info, hope that helps. Any additional help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, please check if it works for you and let me know if I missed anything

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. It helped me to better understand what is going on. Unfortunately it did not work. I ran a db query on Pages to ensure I used the correct data from the url_path column. I even tried `if params[:url_path] = 'page1'`. This made all conditions true (as you explained) and redirected all page loads to 'page2'. Which means the redirect works when the condition returns true. I don't know why the correct conditional statement is not returning true? If you have any more ideas or need additional details from me, please let me know. Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: It would be super helpful to know the value of params[:url_path]
If you can, enter the rails console with `rails c` and write `Page.last.url_path` and post the output

Comment: The value of the url_path that I need to redirect / find in the conditional statement is `/personal/checking-savings`. The value I need to redirect_to is `/checking-savings`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. What I need to know is: 
Does the `url_path` column of the `pages` table contain exactly the string `/personal/checking-savings` formatted in that exact way? 
Because in your if statement you need to specify that exactly (`if params[:url_path] == '/personal/checking-savings'`).
If you are unsure and need to implement a quick solution I'd propose that you checked the following expression in your if statement :
`if params[:url_path]['checking-savings']`
Provided there's no other page that contains `checking-savings` as a substring.